# Why are cookies not shown in chrome dev tool's application tab?

Tags: cookies, jwt, mern, web-development-server

I am new to backend. I was logging in using jwt for auth but have a problem. I am setting the cookie here but I can't see anything in the applications tab of chrome dev tools. However, I can still see the cookie in network tab. [using MERN stack]

```js
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const userDoc = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

    try {
        const passOk = await bcrypt.compare(password, userDoc.password);
        if (passOk) {
            var token = jwt.sign({ username: userDoc.username, id: userDoc.id }, privateKey);
            console.log(token);
            res.cookie('token', token);
            res.status(200).json("Successfully signed up");
        }
        else {
            res.status(404).json("Incorrect Credentials")
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json("Invalid Credentials")
    }

})
```

Here is the network tab: (I don't know if it's safe to share the value fiels, so I blurred it)
[image]

But nothing is shown in applications tab:

[image]

There are 0 errors shown, the reponse I get is '200'. So, what is the problem?